# CSS for two columns which float left

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float, multiple-columns

I want to display two pieces of text side by side in columns using CSS. The left-hand column text is variable in length, and the right-hand text is fixed and always the same length.

I want the two "columns" to float to the left next to each other e.g.

```
[Variable Text] [Fixed text]
```

If the variable text is long I want it to wrap. 
eg,

```
Here is a very long  Hello World
piece of variable
text which wraps
```

My code works if the variable text is short, but I get unwanted whitespaces if the variable text wraps.
eg,

```
Here is a very long               Hello World
piece of variable
text which wraps
```

Here is my code:

```css
#wrapper {
  margin-right: 100px;
}
#left-col {
  float: left;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #CCF;
}
#right-col {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  margin-right: -100px;
  background-color: #FFA;
}
#cleared {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
      <div id="left-col">Here is a very long piece of text which wraps</div>
      <div id="right-col">Hello World</div>
      <div id="cleared"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your issue. If you have long text the `#left-col` wraps and it is OK, but if you have short text you get extra space which you want to avoid?

Comment: could you explain what are the contents (meaning/semantics) you try to put side by side. Is it kind of footnotes ?

Comment: Looks like standard text wrapping to me. The "inline box model"  I think it's called and there's not much you can do about that.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments so far...

@Tasos K - no, it is the opposite of this. I get additional whitespace in between the two columns if the left column wraps.

Comment: The code snippet you provided does not have the issue you describe. Maybe it is something else causing the issue?

Comment: @GCyrillus  To give some context this is for a hotel review website and I want to show the hotel name on the left (which may wrap onto several lines if it is long) and then immediately next to it on the top line I want to show the number of reviews.... eg, Mayfair Hotel (105 reviews)  I don't want any additional spaces in between the hotel name and the number of reviews.

Answer (score 0):

I believe changing `#left-col`'s property `max-width` to other than 100% it will work. For example:

```
#wrapper {
  margin-right: 100px;
}
#left-col {
  float: left;
  max-width: 200px;
  background-color: #CCF;
}
#right-col {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #FFA;
}
#cleared {
  clear: both;
}
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/z9v5uaep/) is a jsfiddle with various text lengths for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

you could maybe update your html to something more meaningfull and easier to style without `class` ou `id`. *(a `<dl>`  is not the most efficient but shows alternative tags easy to style)*

`calc()` can be useful here :)

```css
#wrapper {
width:15em;/* demo purpse */
  }
dl,dt,dd {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  
}
dt {
  float: left;
  clear:left;
  text-align:justify;/* to fill up entire first lines when text wraps*/
  max-width: calc(100% - 100px);
  background-color: #CCF;
  margin-top:0.1em;
}
dd {float:left;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #FFA;
}
```

```html
<dl id="wrapper">
      <dt>1 Here is a very long piece of text which wraps</dt>
      <dd>Hello World 1</dd>
      <dt>2 Here is a very long piece of text which</dt>
      <dd>Hello World 2</dd>
      <dt>3 Here is a very long piece of text</dt>
      <dd>Hello World 3</dd>
      <dt>4 Here is a very long piece</dt>
      <dd>Hello World 4</dd>
      <dt>5 short</dt>
      <dd>5</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Maybe I could ask the question in a different way.... Imagine you have a single column. As text is added the column will automatically increase in size until max-width is reached (let's say 200px for example). Any further text will cause word wrap BUT the column width remains at 200px even if the width of the wrapped text is now less.  How do I get the column to shrink back down?

Comment: @Bilko123 it looks like the fith item of the snippet, isn't ?